# Use find() on map of struct, get "has no member named XXX"

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I defined a structure an use unsigned long long int as key to store structures in the map.
I have another function which finds the structs in the map and do some modification to the structs.

But I got error like this:

```
‘struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const long long unsigned int, sStatics> >’ has no member named Latency
```

Can anyone tell me what is the error comes from?
The following is my code structure:

A.h:

```
#include <map>

struct sStatics;
extern std::map<unsigned long long int, sStatics>  wsmStaticsMap;
```

A.cpp:

```
#include <map>

std::map<unsigned long long int, sStatics>  wsmStaticsMap;
struct sStatics
{
    std::string atcs;
    uint32_t Latency;
    std::vector<unsigned long int> lostWSM;
    unsigned long int wrongOrderCount;
};

static void function_statics(){

    std::map<unsigned long long int,sStatics>::iterator it;
    it = wsmStaticsMap.find(atcs);
    if (it != wsmStaticsMap.end()){
        it->Latency++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should write `it->second.Latency`. Iterator is pointing to an std::pair, it second is the value in the pair. Btw, next time pls write exactly which line give you the error, here it's obvious, but in other cases it can help alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `(it->second).Latency`. It returns a key-value pair. You need to first select the value then an attribute within it.
You can check the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/)

Answer (score 0):

`std::map::find` returns

> Iterator to an element with key equivalent to key. If no such element is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is returned.

It is a `std::pair<Key, Value>`, you need to use `->second` to access the value.

Change

```
it->Latency++;
```

to

```
(it->second).Latency++;
```

Also, use `auto` to simplify

```
auto it = wsmStaticsMap.find(atcs);
```

Comment: it->second->latency ??